# How to parse and extract c# class data

Tags: c#, file, parsing

I have a c# file as in .txt file format, I have to read it dynamically and extract all data available, I need a parser to idenitify 
c# class instances,
C# class fields,
etc..

Can anyone have idea to do this in simple way ?

Comment: By writing your own parser. `.txt` is not a file format. It's a text file that can contain *anything*, including Json or XML data.

Comment: Complete guess, but you could use compiler and then use reflection on compiled code to get the data?

See: `CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFrom`

Comment: Please show class structure, file structure, how data in the file should be "linked" to class properties. And show what did you tried?

Comment: Could you show a [mcve]?

Comment: There *are* some parsers for well-known formats, like CSV, XML, Json, Yaml, etc. What does the file contain?

Comment: @ThomasCook how are you going to use the compiler on a CSV or Json file?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well if it's a CSV or JSON it's not a c# file is it, therefore the question is invalid? (given that the question states "I have a C# file")

Comment: If the question is "I have a string, which is in some format that may be JSON, CSV or any other format that isn't C# and I want to determine if that string can be parsed to a valid, compilable C# string and then, if so, rip out all the data that defines the code (i.e. class names, variable names etc.)" then that is a completely different and much more complex problem that would need breaking down into several sub problems first.

Comment: @ThomasCook the question also mentions data and `txt format`. In any case, if you want to parse source code you should use Roslyn instead of the older CSharpCodeProvider. This will return directly the same information you'd get by using reflection without going through the assembly stage first. That's what the compiler does too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well, I learn something new everyday :-)

Comment: @ThomasCook there are many duplicate questions for C# parsing, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222085/using-roslyn-to-parse-classes-functions-and-properties)

Answer (score 1):

If your C# file is an actual, valid C# file, you could wrap it in a project inside a solution (very simple, one file project), and then compile it. From the EXE file that got generated, you could use reflection to extract types, fields and methods dynamically during runtime.

Another option is to write a basic text parser that recognizes C# keywords and understands what that metadata is, but I think that the first alternative is easier and faster to implement.