# How can I parse C# code snippets using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, parsing, roslyn

I am trying to parse C# code snippets using Microsoft's Roslyn. Example code:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
class TestClass 
{
    void TestMethod ()
    {
        int i;
    }
}");
```

However, I could not understand how can I check the parsing is successful or not.

I found a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222085/using-roslyn-to-parse-classes-functions-and-properties) that explains how to parse using Roslyn. Also, Google it and find several related resources. Unfortunately, I cannot find any way to check whether the parsing is successful or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to use the `GetDiagnostics()` method provided by the `CSharpSyntaxTree` class, because the `GetDiagnostics()` method is called on the `CSharpSyntaxTree` object to retrieve the collection of diagnostics and  if the collection is not empty (errors or warnings), it means that the parsing encountered issues!

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var code = @"
            class TestClass
            {
                void TestMethod()
                {
                    int i;
                }
            }";

        var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
        var diagnostics = tree.GetDiagnostics();

        if (diagnostics.Any())
        {
            // unsuccessful parsing (errors or warnings)
            foreach (var diagnostic in diagnostics)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(diagnostic.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // successful parsing
            Console.WriteLine("successful parsing");
        }
    }
}
```